# How to force homebrew to install to /opt/homebrew on Mac (M2)?

Tags: macos, installation, migration, homebrew, apple-silicon

After using the Macbook's migration utility from an old Intel chip to the newest M2 machine, I started having issues with homebrew.

I uninstalled it and installed it again.

I found the problem. On re-installation, homebrew's default location is still `/usr/local/bin` when it should be `/opt/homebrew`.

You should expect the installation location to be `/opt/homebrew`. This is normally detected automatically but since I used the Mac Migration Assistant, it appears whatever the script looks for to determine this is breaking the installtion.

You should be able to override this though. The way this is normally done is by setting `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` environment variable to the desired location.

```
# .zshrc
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
```

But when I run the installation script, it seems to completely ignore it.

```
~ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"\n
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom
```

I have not found a single good solution to this problem.

Comment: Works for me. The install script is straightforward. It uses the output of `/usr/bin/uname -m` to decide if you are on Apple Silicon (`arm64`) or not. What does that command output on your system?